# html code in class name

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser

For a long and convoluted reason I need to include a html code spaces in a class name - there is no other option.

This class links to some javascript to open and close a div. In Chrome, Safari, IE 8, Firefox 5,6. However it doesn't work in Firefox 3. Why would this be, I don't understand! Anyone have an idea - does firefox handle this character weirdly?

Comment: Show some code - although I don't see how you could be specifying class names with a space. You're probably specifying *two* separate class names

Comment: Please provide the code!

Comment: Could you share an example of your code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Can you please post an example of some sort. Is it a normal class that's been referenced with a normal javascript click event??? please give more detail.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that there is another solution, because yours is not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

In any case, I don't think firefox is going to update its browser to help you.

It sounds like your problem is an unstoppable force against an immovable stone.

But I think with extra work there should be 'an extra option'.

Saying there's 'no other option' is usually, even if justifiably, avoiding another problem and/or being lazy.

As suggested, code would also help us know exactly what you're talking about.